# How to find the right node in Rselenium to press load more buttom on dynamic webpage

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, nodes, rselenium

I want to click the [more recipes](in german: [mehr Rezepte]) Button via Rselenium on the following webpage: https://migusto.migros.ch/de/rezept-uebersicht/mexiko

I tried the following:

```
rD<-rsDriver(browser = 'chrome', port = 427L, chromever = '87.0.4280.88')
remDr<-rD$client

remDr$navigate('https://migusto.migros.ch/de/rezept-uebersicht/mexiko')

load_btn <- remDr$findElement(using = 'class', value = '.icon-right')
load_btn$clickElement
```

Does someone know how to find the right input into findElement() to get the button clicked via Rselenium?

Thank you a lot and BR
David

Answer (score 1):

Rselenium is able to find different types of element inside the html page.
You can use one of these elements.

```
findElement( using = c("xpath", "css selector", "id", "name", "tag name", 
"class name", "link text", "partial link text", "tag name", "xpath"), 
value ="the code that you find in the html page")$clickElement()
```

`class name` : Returns an element whose class name contains the search value; compound class names are not permitted.

`css selector` : Returns an element matching a CSS selector.

`id` : Returns an element whose ID attribute matches the search value.

`name` : Returns an element whose NAME attribute matches the search value.

`link text` : Returns an anchor element whose visible text matches the search value.

`partial link text` : Returns an anchor element whose visible text partially matches the
search value.

`tag name` : Returns an element whose tag name matches the search value.

`xpath` : Returns an element matching an XPath expression.

Belwow a small example:

```
library(RSelenium)
rD<-rsDriver(browser = 'chrome', port = 428L, chromever = '87.0.4280.88')
remDr<-rD$client
remDr$navigate('https://migusto.migros.ch/de/rezept-uebersicht/mexiko')
remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="top"]/div[3]/main/div[1]/div/div[2]/form/a')$clickElement()
```

If you want to deep the argument here the official [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/RSelenium.pdf).